# "Зажечь свет"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Знаю, что "зажечь лампочку" - выражение неграмотное. Но будет ли ошибкой сказать "зажечь свет в комнате"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И ошибкой не будет, и выражение вполне грамотное.

1. что.
   Заставить гореть; вызвать горение. З. свечу. З. сигарету. З. газ. З. фитиль в керосиновой лампе. З. запал у пушки. З. костёр. З. спичку. З. спичками. Молния зажгла дерево.   
   **Заставить светиться, светить, испускать свет**. З. огонь, свет, настольную лампочку, торшер. З. электричество. З. ёлку (осветить ёлку свечами, лампочками).
   ....
   (Кузнецов)

Точно также как обратное действие возможно *гасить* и *тушить*, правда с несколько разным акцентом.